# These wget and cURL commands work on command line but not in a Bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, downloads, wget, curl

I am trying to download an images off a website and have tried:

```
curl -o img.jpg (URL)
wget (URL) -O img.jpg
wget --save-headers -U "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.17  (KHTML,   Gecko) Ubuntu/11.04 Chromium/11.0.654.0 Chrome/11.0.654.0  Safari/534.17" (URL) -O img.jpg
```

In every case the command works when I run it normally it in the terminal. However, as soon as I try to incorporate it in some bash script the image corrupts with the following message:

```
Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x48 0x54).
```

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#I pass the url as a parameter - http://img1.goodfon.su/wallpaper/original/f/c3/les-eli-lokomotiv-noch-sneg.jpg

#wget --save-headers -k -U "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.17  (KHTML,   Gecko) Ubuntu/11.04 Chromium/11.0.654.0 Chrome/11.0.654.0  Safari/534.17" $1 -O img.jpg
#curl -o img.jpg $1
wget $1 -O img.jpg

avconv -framerate 25 -f image2 -i img.jpg -c:v h264 -crf 1 out.mov
```

Comment: You should add the full script complete of the picture's URL, i suspect the latter is expanding to an invalid URL when running into the script

Comment: It has been added, pictures URL - http://img1.goodfon.su/wallpaper/original/f/c3/les-eli-lokomotiv-noch-sneg.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The two hex numbers in

```
Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x48 0x54
```

translate to ASCII `HT` which I guess continues to `HTTP[...]`. Check the header of the file with `xxd -l 20 img.jpg`. This is to be expected output from the last command you posted, since

```
wget --save-headers
```

instructs `wget` to prepend the output with the `HTTP` header of the answer.

The two other invocations won't do that.

---

I just tested your script and it works with either `curl` or `wget`. For `wget` to download the file, a user string `-U` is needed, otherwise the server refuses. Either use

```
curl -o img.jpg $1
```

or

```
wget -U "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.17  (KHTML,   Gecko) Ubuntu/11.04 Chromium/11.0.654.0 Chrome/11.0.654.0  Safari/534.17" $1 -O img.jpg
```

*without* `--save-headers`.